# Can't boot in windows 8 after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, windows

As advised I am asking here about my problem. After upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 I can't boot in windows 8.1. Right away after upgrade I noticed that few of my previous options are missing in grub. Then I tried booting in ubuntu and it works. But booting windows doesn't. I only get error reading file for less than a second and than it returns me back in grub. I tried boot-repair with live cd in ubuntu 13.10 as advised. It ran through and it give me this [http://paste.ubuntu.com/7299246/.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7299246/) I would be really grateful if someone would check it and tell me if something is wrong. Or give some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu 14.04 and try updating Grub

sudo update-grub

That will check for the other OS that are installed in your machine and updates grub then reboot to see if it worked

If that did not work then you have to repair your windows boot-loader first and then re-install grub

for windows boot loader

=> u need a windows 8 repair disc or windows 8 live usb or live cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to

Repair=>System Recovery Options=>command prompt

type the following two commands in cmd exactly

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again

Now back to grub boot loader

=> u need ubuntu live usb and use " load ubuntu without install" then install boot-repair and repair grub u can see it in this how it is done https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

if u install windows boot loader u can create a ubutnu live usb in windows using unetbootin(in case if u have a single pendrive currently)

i hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I finally got some time and tried your tips. Both didn't help. With boot repair I got this link http://paste.ubuntu.com/7314407/. Should I just give up on getting into windows again and format every thing? I would not loose any very important files.

Comment: Windows repair from cmd didn't it work

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that too as it didn't change any of the boot options.

Comment: can you give the screen shots of what you did, that way of restoring windwos bootloader is the best way i know it never failed

Comment: i will see if i can find any problem and post to you later

Comment: Can I post screens later this evening when I get to my desktop where I have all the things to make win8 live usb (you want me to go through the first proces again right? :) ).

Comment: Thats fine take the screen shots of repairing steps

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3d17p4 ->
http://prntscr.com/3d1bye ->
http://prntscr.com/3d1cla ->
http://prntscr.com/3d1dfv ->
http://prntscr.com/3d1evh ->
http://prntscr.com/3d1fpx -> This was my proces. After this I did boot-repair in 13.10 and it went the same way as befor and still I cant boot in Windows.

Comment: after that cmd successful did you tried booting into windows

Comment: your system have a UEFI BIOS its a safety mechanism to prevent malicious software from booting in your PC, as well as “non authorized” operating systems to your windows 8. Go to Bios, search for the option “Secureboot” and change it to “Disabled”.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late answer I was away from home for spring holidays. Yes my computer has UEFI but I already disable my secure boot. And it didn't changed a thing. Also right after cmd was successful I tried booting in and it didn't work. And the second time I did this cmd thing I went right away into repairing grub. Also didn't work. I am probably gonna format the disk. Unless you have any other idea. Thanks for your help a lot :)